# Android - Null Pointer Exception on backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm getting NPE on backstack. To combat OOM issue, I read that I need to nullify all references inside the `Fragment`, especially `Bitmaps`. So what I did is : when a `Fragment` is replaced, I set every variable to null, except the `Adapter` for `RecyclerView` as I need to use the content again..

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    annihilateView();
}
```

And the `onCreateView` :

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lobi, container, false);
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        utilities = new Utilities(BottomLobiFragment.this.getActivity());

        ((NewsfeedActivity)getActivity()).hideBottomToolbarMarket();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        userIdString = sharedPreferencesList.userIDString;
        userAliasString = sharedPreferencesList.userAliasString;
        loginSharedPrefsString = sharedPreferencesList.loginSharedPreference;
//        mPrefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences(loginSharedPrefsString, getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);

        userId = sharedPreferenceUtilities.getValue(BottomLobiFragment.this.getActivity(), loginSharedPrefsString, userIdString);
        userAlias = sharedPreferenceUtilities.getValue(BottomLobiFragment.this.getActivity(), loginSharedPrefsString, userAliasString);

        lobiProgressBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_lobi_progressBar);
        lobiProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.miBlue),
                android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        noPostTV = (OpenSansFont)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_lobi_noPostTextView);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_lobi_recyclerView);

        handler = new Handler();
        manager = new LinearLayoutManager(BottomLobiFragment.this.getActivity(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
//        recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(VIEW_TYPE,0);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_lobi_swipe_container);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        upperToolbarInit();

        if(getArguments() != null){
            Parcelable savedRecyclerLayoutState = getArguments().getParcelable(utilities.BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT);
            if(savedRecyclerLayoutState == null){
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = sharedPreferenceUtilities.getValue(BottomLobiFragment.this.getActivity(), sharedPreferencesList.loginSharedPreference, utilities.lobbyPostListKey);
                //(utilities.lobbyPostListKey, "");
                PostListSharedPrefs postListApiFrmJson = gson.fromJson(json, PostListSharedPrefs.class);
                if(postListApiFrmJson != null){
                    lobiAdapter = new LobiAdapter();
                    lobiAdapter.setDisplay(width, height);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(lobiAdapter);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
                    lobiAdapter.addList(postListApiFrmJson.posts);
                    counter += postListApiFrmJson.posts.size();
                    setIsLoaded();
                    setBlankLoaded();
                } else {
                    refreshView();
                }
            } else {
                manager.onRestoreInstanceState(savedRecyclerLayoutState);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(lobiAdapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
                lobiProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else if(getArguments() == null){
            refreshView();
        }
```

The problem is, `onCreateView` should be called again everytime user goes to backstack as per Fragment Lifecycle, yes? Because I've re referenced everything in the `onCreateView` and it throws NPE, but if I don't set everything to null in `onDestroyView`, it works fine.. Or am I just reading the Lifecycle wrong?

Comment: @saeed Um I failed to understand what the setting of `listSelector` to null has to do with my NPE problem.. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @saeed What I'm asking is NPE when user goes to backstack, not about display..

Comment: oo iam sorry  the above links are not answer for your quistian

Comment: @saeed Yes, that's what I thought lol, good luck on answering the other question :D

Comment: put your stacktrace log which will be helpful.

Comment: The onCreateView method is called when the fragment is opened from backstack, so your NPE must be caused for some other reason: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

Comment: @RameshKumar Will do in a couple of mins, recreating the problem.. @Honza Musil It only happens when I nullify the `View`s in the `Fragment`.. Do you know what else might have happened?

Comment: Hey this is weird! It doesn't happen anymore now! But I suspect it'll happen again in the future, will keep nullifying everything in `onDestroyView`, I might not be working on the same `Fragment` which gave me NPE last time, will update when I meet with the same problem again